# My Mongoose Get request returns a favicon.ico instead of a string

Tags: node.js, mongoose, heroku, get, favicon

I tried to make this Get request with Mongoose but instead of the `titleName`the value that returns is Favicon.ico.
I think the problem is something at app.get("/:titleName..")
In localhost there is no problem but when i try to deploy my app in Heroku i get a H:13 problem and crash.

```
app.get("/:titleName", function (req, res) {
  const defaulttitleName = _.capitalize(req.params.titleName);
  req.params.titleName;
  List.findOne({ name: defaulttitleName }, function (err, foundList) {
    if (!err) {
      if (!foundList) {
        const list = new List({
          name: defaulttitleName,
          items: defaultItems,
        });

        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + defaulttitleName);
      } else {
        res.render("list", {
          listTitle: foundList.name,
          newListItems: foundList.items,
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to make this Get request with Mongoose but instead of the `titleName`the value that returns is Favicon.ico.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the same "favicon.ico" in similar case but when I changed my route from `/:titleName` to `/list/:titleName`.
It just returns a `titlename`,
Don't know the reason why it returns `favicon.ico` when requested from `/:titlename`.